# How to overwrite a file inside docker on Runtime

Tags: docker

I want to overwrite a file that is inside a docker container with a file of same name on my host operating system.

Docker run `-v` does not overwrites this file as both file's name is same.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is the container one that you have control over (e.g. your own image)? If so, you could mount the directory containing the file, and copy it over in your entrypoint script. Even if you don't, you could override the entry point with your own, to copy the file and then run the default entry point.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the remark about `-v` not working due to the name. Can you edit the question to include the actual command you are running?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to keep the file synced between your host and your docker instance. You should use the docker run -v option as you wrote in the question but instead of giving the file name, you should use the folder name.

Further read on the topic: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker cp` to replace the file inside the Container with the one from the host. Thus you dont have to restart the container as e.g using volume mounts. [Docker Cp Ref.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Comment: Thank you, this made my day :)